# webservice in C#, wse 2.0

Tags: c#, import, webservice-client

I have a problem.

I import this in to my program:

```
using Microsoft.Web.Services2;
using Microsoft.Web.Services2.Addressing;
using Microsoft.Web.Services2.Messaging;
```

I've also added Microsoft.Web.Services2.dll to my project, but I still get an error when I try to compile program ... What is wrong?

I get these errors:

Error 4 The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 
Error 6 The type or namespace name 'SoapServiceAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

more code:

```
[SoapService("http://www.example.org/test/")]
public class Payment : SoapClient 
{
    public Payment() : base( new Uri("http://localhost:8080/TestServer/services/testSOAP") )
    {
    }

    [SoapMethod("http://www.example.org/test/paymant")]
    public paymantResponse paymant( paymant request )
    {
        return (paymantResponse)base.SendRequestResponse("paymant", request).GetBodyObject( typeof(paymantResponse), SoapServiceAttribute.TargetNamespace);
    }

    public IAsyncResult Beginpaymant( paymant request, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
    {
        return base.BeginSendRequestResponse("paymant", request, callback, asyncState);
    }

    public paymantResponse Endpaymant( System.IAsyncResult asyncResult )
    {
        return (paymantResponse)base.EndSendRequestResponse(asyncResult).GetBodyObject( typeof(paymantResponse), SoapServiceAttribute.TargetNamespace);
    }
```

Everything connected with SoapService, SoapClient, SoapService attribute ... can*t get namespace or should I say reference ...
    }

Comment: Is there any reason you are using the *ancient* wse2 framework?

Comment: Are you sure you've added the DLL as a reference?

Comment: Which is the newest WSE? Wse 3.0 ? Sorry, but I'm new to web services.

Comment: I've added DLL as reference to my project yes.